Confusion about language in Alfsen's proof of existence and (essential) uniqueness of Haar measure
Notation: $L^{+}$ is the space of non-negative, continuous, compactly supported functions on a locally compact group $G$.
On page 108 of Alfsen's Simplified Constructive Proof of Existence and Uniqueness of Haar Measure, he defines a functional on $L^{+}$ to be admissible if it is non-zero, isotone (or order-preserving), positively homogeneous, additive, and left-invariant. On the same page, he then associates a pre-ordering to each admissible functional $I$ defined by$$f\le g\mod I\iff I(f)\le I(g).$$My question: Alfsen never defined what it means for a functional to be order-preserving, so I assumed he meant a functional $I$ is isotone if $$f,g\in L^{+}$$ and $$f(x)\le g(x)$$ for all $x\in G$, then $I(f)\le I(g)$. This, to me, was the only sensible thing. However, the pre-order he associates to an admissible functional now seems to be redundant, since $I$ is already order-preserving (in the sense that I understand). Is my assumption of what isotone functionals are incorrect? Thank you very much for your help.
